# Margin and positioning of input elements

Tags: html

I want to partition a block into two separate smaller blocks. For that, I am using the following HTML:

```
<div style="width: 300px; height: 200px; background-color: red; ">
    <div style="display: inline-block; width: 100px; height: 200px; background-color: lightblue;">
    </div>
    <div style="display: inline-block; width: 196px; height: 200px; background-color: green;">
    </div>
</div>
```

Result:

[image: Preview #1]

Here's the first problem: As you can see, there is still some of the (red) background visible between the two boxes (grey & green). I don't know how to get rid of that space - both `div` elements already have a margin, border and padding of 0. When I increase the width of the green `div` element to 200px (as it should be), the element jumps out of its parent since it grew too large.

Is there any default padding, or a rule that browsers must add some space between simple elements? If so, how can I get rid of it?

The second issue arises when I add a `input` tag to the green `div`:

```
<div style="width: 300px; height: 200px; background-color: red; ">
    <div style="display: inline-block; width: 100px; height: 200px; background-color: lightblue;">
    </div>
    <div style="display: inline-block; width: 196px; height: 200px; background-color: green;">
        <input type='submit' value='Details'/> <!-- new -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, for some reason, the green `div` is forced down again:

[image: Preview #2]

The `input` element (and the containing `div` by extension) is moved down to the bottom of the red `div`. I found out I can stop that by using `position: absolute` but I'm confused as to why it behaves like this at all. It seems like there's something more subtle going wrong, but I don't know what.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: @CBroe That's an interesting article  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Instead of `display:inline-block` use `float`

```
<div style="width: 300px; height: 200px; background-color: red; ">
    <div style="float: left; width: 100px; height: 200px; background-color: lightblue;">
    </div>
    <div style="float: right; width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: green;">
        <input type='submit' value='Details'/> <!-- new -->
    </div>
</div>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/fuhup/1/edit)**

Comment: That works, thanks. Do you know *why* the input element messes up the formatting when I use `inline-block`?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="width: 300px; height: 200px; background-color: red; ">
    <div style="display: inline-block; width: 100px; height: 200px; background-color: lightblue;">
    </div>
    <div style="display: inline-block;position:fixed; width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: green;">
          <input type='submit' value='Details'/>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/hsakapandit/c6AUF/